# Sql queries returning different results in different tabs

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I've been executing some SQL commands (various inserts, updates and deletes) on one query window, and when I check the results on the same query window, those queries executed, but when I check in other command window about the results of the command, it's like I never executed anything.

For example, in the original query window I did

```
DELETE FROM emBaseSocios
```

then I execute

```
SELECT * FROM emBaseSocios
```

which returns nothing of course

But if I open another window pointing at the same database and do

```
SELECT * FROM emBaseSocios
```

it returns all rows that were there before deleting like nothing happened
and when I try to DELETE there it takes too much time

What could be the issue here?

Comment: are you using transactions?

Comment: Add 'commit;' after the delete.

Comment: If you're using a snapshot isolation level, this would be expected - the second connection will not know *anything* about your changes until you've **committed** them in the first query window!

Comment: I used some  queries without transactions and the one that had had the commit.

Comment: How do I commit everything done in the first query window then?

Comment: In the first query window, run `WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT;`

Answer (score 0):

"What could be the issue here?"

The transactional stuff in the question comments "could" be the issue, certainly. However, another possibility is that the windows are not actually connected to the same DB/Instance/Server. If you have multiple copies of you DB around or very similar databases that you switch between it is completely possible to get mixed up--I've done it.

One way thing you can do to help yourself avoid such thins is to customize the colour of you your staus bar per connection. [Here are some instructions](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1871/customizing-the-status-bar-for-each-sql-server-ssms-connection/).